# Error message: root element is missing

Tags: chocolatey

When updating all [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) packages, the following error message appears:

```
Root element is missing.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

### chocolatey.log details

```
2020-05-19 11:44:14,947 22876 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2020-05-19 11:44:14,953 22876 [ERROR] - Root element is missing.
2020-05-19 11:44:14,958 22876 [ERROR] - More Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at NuGet.XmlUtility.LoadSafe(Stream input, Boolean ignoreWhiteSpace)
   at NuGet.Manifest.ReadFrom(Stream stream, IPropertyProvider propertyProvider, Boolean validateSchema)
   at NuGet.LocalPackage.ReadManifest(Stream manifestStream)
   at NuGet.UnzippedPackage.EnsureManifest(String manifestFilePath)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.OpenPackage(String path)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.GetPackage(Func`2 openPackage, String path)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.<GetPackages>d__28.MoveNext()
   at NuGet.CollectionExtensions.AddRange[T](ICollection`1 collection, IEnumerable`1 items)
   at NuGet.LocalPackageRepository.FindPackagesById(Func`2 openPackage, String packageId)
   at NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackagesById(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId)
   at NuGet.PackageRepositoryExtensions.FindPackage(IPackageRepository repository, String packageId, SemanticVersion version, IPackageConstraintProvider constraintProvider, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean allowUnlisted)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.NugetService.upgrade_run(ChocolateyConfiguration config, Action`1 continueAction, Boolean performAction, Action`1 beforeUpgradeAction)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.NugetService.upgrade_run(ChocolateyConfiguration config, Action`1 continueAction, Action`1 beforeUpgradeAction)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.ChocolateyPackageService.perform_source_runner_function[T](ChocolateyConfiguration config, Func`2 function)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.ChocolateyPackageService.upgrade_run(ChocolateyConfiguration config)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.runners.GenericRunner.run(ChocolateyConfiguration config, Container container, Boolean isConsole, Action`1 parseArgs)
   at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.runners.ConsoleApplication.run(String[] args, ChocolateyConfiguration config, Container container)
   at chocolatey.console.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

### Version info

Tested with Chocolatey v0.10.15

Answer (score 2):

### Cause

Zero byte nupkgs or nuspec files cause this issue. These package files are downloaded from the Chocolatey nuget server and can be corrupted/empty, for example when the disk is full.

### Workaround

Find and remove the zero byte file and that should fix the issue. This is a manual workaround until Chocolatey can handle this.

Find and delete empty `*.nu*` files in this directory tree:

> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib

### Source and issue status

Issue: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/717

Comment: You can remove those empty files using this PowerShell command `ChildItem C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\*\*.nu* | where Length -eq 0 | Del`